Sound isn't working after Ubuntu installing
Huawei MateBook D14 NbDE-WDH9
Sound isn't working after Ubuntu installing
$ sudo lspci | grep audio

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
$ aplay -l

aplay: device_list:277: no soundcards found...

What Ubuntu? Desktop or server? Version?

Desktop, 24.04 LTS

There is a github repository which might work https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix?tab=readme-ov-file. Enter the following commands and reboot. git clone https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix and cd huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix and bash install.sh

isn't worked for me

Please create an issue in that GitHub repository.
